# Is a refinement of an open cover also a cover?

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

[image]
[image]

I am trying to understand the above proposition. So according to the definition of $\text{dim}\, X$, $\mathcal{W}$ is a refinement of the open cover. What I don't understand is why is it that any point $x$ in $X$ must be in some member of $\mathcal{W}$? Does this imply that the refinement $\mathcal{W}$ is also a cover of $X$? Why is this not mentioned in the definition?

Comment: A refinement of a cover is by definition another cover (with some properties), this is probably written in the book you're reading where a refinement is defined (which book is that by the way?)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, Dimension Theory of General Spaces by Alan R. Pears.

Comment: page 4: "a **covering** $\{B_\gamma\}_{\gamma\in\Gamma}$ is said to be a refinement of a covering $\{A_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ if..."

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As Codenotti already pointed out, the relation of refinement is defined between **covers** of a space. So it's sort of implicit in the use of the word refinement, as it were.